# How can I access from outside my docker container in mac?

Tags: macos, docker

I have a docker container running in a default vm in mac, I've already mapped the ports of my particular application to the ports of the vm. Once I've done that I can access my application by doing:

```
curl $(docker-machine ip default):9003
```

After that I've mapped my vm port to my localhost by doing port forwarding this way:

```
VBoxManage controlvm default natpf1 "9003,tcp,127.0.0.1,9003,,9003"
```

Once I've done that I get a response of my application from my localhost

```
curl localhost:9003
```

My question is: How can I access this application from the outside world or even from my own network? I've tried opening a port in my mac with:

```
pass in inet proto tcp from any to any port 9003
```

but still the port shows as closed with nmap. Does anyone knows what I'm missing?

Comment: you only bound localhost (127.0.0.1). you need to bind to whatever your vm's "go outside" ip is.

Comment: great totally missed it, post it as a reply and I will accept it

Comment: You can find the solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44384542/how-can-i-map-a-shared-folder-from-my-container-on-mac/44529789#44529789

Answer (score 0):

You can either bind your socket to localhost if the `docker-run` option `--net=host` is used, hence the local stack, as well as NICs, are shared between the host and the container(s).

OTOH, if the `docker-run` option `-p` is used then if the socket is bound to a localhost IP address then the service cannot be accessed from outside the container.

---

Wait for the answer of @marc-b though, he gave it the first.